# How can I use two variables in the urls.py with Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

Hello I have this line in my urls.py using Django :

```
re_path(r'exporting/(?P<var1>)/(?P<var2>.+)', views.myfunction, name='myfunction')
```

And actually in my js file the url looks like something like this :

```
window.location = Url + 'pdf/myfunction/' + var1 + '/' + var2 + '';
```

But it does not work when I try to see the page...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: should be `(?P<var1>.+)` ?

Comment: What do you mean with it does not work? Your location has `pdf/myfunction` whereas the url has `exporting/`?

Comment: Could you add the view function?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
url('reset/<var2>/<var1>/', views, name='apple'),
```